# How to refit opencv image as MFC view resizes

Tags: opencv, mfc, resize

I am following [this question to display OpenCV image on MFC view.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8501753/1194873) And it works great. But one thing I would like to do is to allow user to see rescaled view of the image as he/she resizes the window (of view). What would be best way to do this? Should I have the opencv image rescaled to the resized window and display it on the view again?

Comment: You have to stretch the image to fit the view size any way, either use GDI object or OpenCV. There is not much difference between these two implementations in terms of efficiency. But is windows resizing a frequent operation that one really need to concern?

Comment: I guess not. But we need to provide that functionality to user. I guess I need to do that with OpenCV. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can respond to OnSize windows event using [Resize](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/imgproc_geometric_image_transformations.html#resize) function in OpenCV, or use [CDC::StretchBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3k5s37a5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to achieve this.