# Does this leak memory? How can I prevent it?

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-leaks, mfc

I see that this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501753/how-to-display-opencv-mat-on-mfc-view)'s answer is really popular regarding how to print a cv::Mat image into an MFC application.

However, I was wondering if there is a memory leak there? or if there is none, how is that possible?

In specific, I'm wondering about the `memset(bmih, 0, sizeof(*bmih))` part. Is it that MFC somehow manages the memory here? Can someone provide some information regarding this?

```
void COpenCVTestView::FillBitmapInfo(BITMAPINFO* bmi, int width, int height, int bpp, int origin) 
{ 
assert(bmi && width >= 0 && height >= 0 && (bpp == 8 || bpp == 24 || bpp == 32)); 

BITMAPINFOHEADER* bmih = &(bmi->bmiHeader); 
// this part shouldn't leak?
memset(bmih, 0, sizeof(*bmih)); 
bmih->biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); 
bmih->biWidth = width; 
bmih->biHeight = origin ? abs(height) : -abs(height); 
bmih->biPlanes = 1; 
bmih->biBitCount = (unsigned short)bpp; 
bmih->biCompression = BI_RGB; 

if (bpp == 8) 
{ 
    RGBQUAD* palette = bmi->bmiColors; 

            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) 
    { 
        palette[i].rgbBlue = palette[i].rgbGreen = palette[i].rgbRed = (BYTE)i; 
        palette[i].rgbReserved = 0; 
    } 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where do you see a memory leak?  There's no dynamic allocation, and no
pointer manipulation.  A `memset` coul cause a memory leak, if it
overwrote a pointer to dynamically allocated memory, but there's no
pointer in a `BITMAPINFOHEADER`, just integers.

Answer (score 2):

The `memset` just fills the `bmih` object with zeros in this case. So there is no memory leak.

The `FillBitmapInfo` method is called with a pointer to a `BITMAPINFO` object that was previously allocated somewhere else. `bmih` is just a reference to the `bmiHeader` member of the `BITMAPINFO` struct. `memset` just assigns a value to the memory region referenced by `bmih`.

Answer (score 2):

A `memset()` doesn't cause a memory leak. That just writes 0x00 bytes into part of the memory pointed to by `bmi`. There is not enough code here to determine whether any memory is leaked.