# How to display opencv frames in MFC?

Tags: opencv, mfc, webcam

I'm writing an opencv code, and want to use MFC to show frames on GUI.

The question is I don't know how.

In the OnInitDialog()

If I tried to embed the cvWindow to the MFC Form, and this could work.

```
display = new IplImage(trackview);//trackview is a totally black Mat.
    cvNamedWindow("IDC_STATIC_OUTPUT", 0); 
    cvResizeWindow("IDC_STATIC_OUTPUT", 480, 640);

    hWnd = (HWND) cvGetWindowHandle("IDC_STATIC_OUTPUT"); 
    hParent = ::GetParent(hWnd); 
     ::SetParent(hWnd, GetDlgItem(ID_DISPLAY)->m_hWnd); 
     ::ShowWindow(hParent, SW_HIDE); 

    cvShowImage("IDC_STATIC_OUTPUT", display);
```

[image]

But when I embed OpenCV code and open the webcam, the GUI is not responding, and the frame cannot be shown. Even I just add this sample code (open webcam) to OnInitDialog(), the application form will not be shown.

It is strange that I wrote a "imwrite("frame.png",tmp)", the frame could be written to file. But the GUI is not responding.

```
while( true )
    {
        CvCapture* capture;
        capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        Mat tmp(frame);
        imwrite("frame.png",tmp);
    }
```

BTW, are there any better way to show OpenCV IplImage on MFC? There's a cvvImage.showImage() function, but it is discarded in Opecv 2.4 version.

Comment: Hi did you find anyway to use opencv in mfc, or mfc is not suitable for using opencv, i am also looking for some to tell what to use to develop computer vision app in c++

Answer (score 1):

Please try cvWaitkey(30) in the while loop. cvShowImage may need some time to display the image.

Comment: This method doesn't work for me. I finally give up using MFC.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly display the IplImage on MFC GUI. The reason it doesn't work is because you were trying to display the image on opencv Window which is not MFC window. 
As of how to display it on MFC;

```
(1) Use CImage(CvvImage )
(2) Fill in bitmap and display.
```

The answer can be located here:

[How to display OpenCV Mat on MFC View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501753/how-to-display-opencv-mat-on-mfc-view)